# JsonPath: getting first element in string list

Tags: json, jsonpath

On https://jsonpath.com I have below example, using expression

```
$.phoneNumbers[?(@.id < 3)].number
```

on below JSON object.

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "age"      : 26,
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type"  : "iPhone",
      "number": "0123-4567-1111",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "type"  : "home",
      "number": "0123-4567-2222",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "type"  : "home",
      "number": "0123-4567-3333",
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Result is

```
[
  "0123-4567-1111",
  "0123-4567-2222"
]
```

---

#### Question

I only want the first string `"0123-4567-1111"`, but appending `[0]` to my expression does not work. Expression `$.phoneNumbers[?(@.id < 3)].number[0]` gives result `["0","0"]`. How can I get the first returned string?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you were very close to it by using this expression -

> $.phoneNumbers[?(@.id < 3)].number[0]

In this expression you used `id` but in the json there is no id key so it resulted in undefined

try the expression like this using index -

```
 $.phoneNumbers[0].number
```

It will return number from the first object of phoneNumbers list as : `["0123-4567-8888"]`

If you want to go by conditional basis use the below expression which will return the number of type iphone -

```
$.phoneNumbers[?(@.type == 'iPhone')].number
```

**Output** -

```
["0123-4567-8888"]
```

Comment: Thanks @Dev. This unfortunately seems to be getting around the problem. If I have multiple items of type `iPhone` then I think this solution suffers the same problem I originally described.

Comment: It does not, see the complete answer. I have given a choice as per the sample data. Now if only first occurrence of number you want you can go for the index as described in the answer. Also what ever you have explain in the question is not what you are saying in the comment. Your JSON expression is incorrect in first place.